# Javascript - fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Im quite new to programming and I'm stuck with a problem.

This is my code :

```
         fetch('https://feed.tunein.com/profiles/s9615/nowPlaying')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
```

This is the response I get back :

```
{
  Header: { Title: 'Radio 1', Subtitle: 'BQL - Muza' },       
  Primary: {
    GuideId: 's9615',
    Image: 'http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s9615q.png',
    Title: 'Radio 1',
    Subtitle: 'Več dobre glasbe'
  },
  Secondary: {
    GuideId: 'o0',
    Image: 'http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s9615q.png',
    Title: 'BQL - Muza',
    Subtitle: 'Radio 1',
    FullScreen: true
  },
  Ads: {
    CanShowAds: true,
    CanShowPrerollAds: true,
    CanShowCompanionAds: false,
    CanShowVideoPrerollAds: false
  },
  Echo: {
    CanEcho: false,
    EchoCount: 0,
    TargetItemId: 's9615',
    Scope: 's9615',
    Url: '',
    FeedTag: 's9615'
  },
  React: {
    CanReact: false,
    TargetItemId: 's9615',
    Scope: 's9615',
    Url: 'https://api.radiotime.com/profiles/me/activities?itemToken=BgwMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABjyUAAAEMAY8lAAABjyUAAA',
    Reactions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  Donate: { CanDonate: false },
  Share: { CanShare: true, ShareUrl: 'http://tun.in/selA9' },
  Follow: { Options: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  Record: { CanRecord: false },
  Classification: {
    ContentType: 'music',
    IsEvent: false,
    IsOnDemand: false,
    IsFamilyContent: false,
    IsMatureContent: false,
    GenreId: 'g141'
  },
  Link: { WebUrl: 'http://www.radio1.si/' },
  Ttl: 18,
  Token: 'eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwidCI6IjIwMjAtMDQtMjRUMjM6NDA6MTAuNzIwNDY4OVoifQ'
}
```

So I'm trying to extract the current playing song which is stored in Secondary - Title. So how could i extract it?

Thank you for your help and also sorry about my english since it is not my first language!

Comment: You can access the inner object: `fetch('https://feed.tunein.com/profiles/s9615/nowPlaying').then(response => response.json()).then(json => json.Secondary.Title)`. Better to add null checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `console.log(data)`, access the title by using `console.log(data.Secondary.Title)`

You will probably then want to do something with the data instead of just log it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

nested objects can be accessed as follows:

```js
const exampleObject = { val0 : {val1: {val2:{val3:"val3"}}}}
const val3 = exampleObject.val0.val1.val2.val3
```

So, You can simply call :`data.Secondary.Title`

```js
const data = {
  Header: { Title: 'Radio 1', Subtitle: 'BQL - Muza' },       
  Primary: {
    GuideId: 's9615',
    Image: 'http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s9615q.png',
    Title: 'Radio 1',
    Subtitle: 'Več dobre glasbe'
  },
  Secondary: {
    GuideId: 'o0',
    Image: 'http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s9615q.png',
    Title: 'BQL - Muza',
    Subtitle: 'Radio 1',
    FullScreen: true
  },
  Ads: {
    CanShowAds: true,
    CanShowPrerollAds: true,
    CanShowCompanionAds: false,
    CanShowVideoPrerollAds: false
  },
  Echo: {
    CanEcho: false,
    EchoCount: 0,
    TargetItemId: 's9615',
    Scope: 's9615',
    Url: '',
    FeedTag: 's9615'
  },
  React: {
    CanReact: false,
    TargetItemId: 's9615',
    Scope: 's9615',
    Url: 'https://api.radiotime.com/profiles/me/activities?itemToken=BgwMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABjyUAAAEMAY8lAAABjyUAAA',
    Reactions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  Donate: { CanDonate: false },
  Share: { CanShare: true, ShareUrl: 'http://tun.in/selA9' },
  Follow: { Options: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  Record: { CanRecord: false },
  Classification: {
    ContentType: 'music',
    IsEvent: false,
    IsOnDemand: false,
    IsFamilyContent: false,
    IsMatureContent: false,
    GenreId: 'g141'
  },
  Link: { WebUrl: 'http://www.radio1.si/' },
  Ttl: 18,
  Token: 'eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwidCI6IjIwMjAtMDQtMjRUMjM6NDA6MTAuNzIwNDY4OVoifQ'
}

console.log(data.Secondary.Title)
```

**Warning:**

Intermediate nulls can throw errors like "`cannot read property Title of undefined`". So, you have to handle that situation while accessing. For your case:

```js
const title = data.Secondary?data.Secondary.Title:null
if(title){//do whatever}
else{//handle error}
```