# Javascript - fetch extract title

Tags: javascript, fetch

Im quite new to programming and I'm stuck with a problem.

This is my code :

```
fetch("https://radiocenter.si/api/module/json/RadioSchedule/JsonModule/GetStreamInfo", {
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        "body": "RadioStreamId=1&SystemName=&Title=&Description=&Icon%5BId%5D=0&Stream=&XmlStream=&Position=&Activated=true",
        "method": "POST",
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
```

This is the response I get back :

```
{
  data: [
    {
      title: 'POWER OVER ME',
      artist: 'DERMOT KENNEDY',
      titleArtist: 'DERMOT KENNEDY - POWER OVER ME',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/28/58/04_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [],
      artistLink: [Object],
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 1423,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: false
    },
    {
      title: 'LOCO CONTIGO',
      artist: 'DJ SNAKE',
      titleArtist: 'DJ SNAKE - LOCO CONTIGO',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/30/70/14_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [Array],
      artistLink: [Object],
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 154,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: true
    },
    {
      title: 'KNOW YOUR WORTH',
      artist: 'KHALID FT. DISCLOSURE',
      titleArtist: 'KHALID FT. DISCLOSURE - KNOW YOUR WORTH',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/30/54/74_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [],
      artistLink: null,
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 0,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: false
    },
    {
      title: 'MORE THAN YOU KNOW',
      artist: 'AXWELL & INGROSSO',
      titleArtist: 'AXWELL & INGROSSO - MORE THAN YOU KNOW',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/25/11/25_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [],
      artistLink: null,
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 0,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: false
    },
    {
      title: 'EVERYTHING I WANTED',
      artist: 'BILLIE EILISH',
      titleArtist: 'BILLIE EILISH - EVERYTHING I WANTED',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/30/22/72_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [],
      artistLink: [Object],
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 1425,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: false
    }
  ],
  created: '2020-04-25T00:37:12.0247937Z',
  streamName: '',
  streamImage: 'http://radiocenter.si/XML/streamImages/default.svg',
  errors: []
}
```

So I'm trying to extract the current playing song which is stored in title, here :

```
{
      title: 'KNOW YOUR WORTH',
      artist: 'KHALID FT. DISCLOSURE',
      titleArtist: 'KHALID FT. DISCLOSURE - KNOW YOUR WORTH',
      picture: 'http://www.radiocenter.si/XML/covers/music/00/00/30/54/74_320.jpg',
      socialLinks: [],
      artistLink: null,
      embedVideoRequest: '/api/module/json/MusicArtists/JsonModule/GetArtistEmbedVideos',
      artistId: 0,
      hasAnyEmbedVideos: false
    }
```

So how could i extract it?

Thank you for your help and also sorry about my english since it is not my first language!

Comment: Almost same question asked a few minutes before. Coincidence? Aliens? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419225/javascript-fetch

Comment: Even the last part `Thank you for your help and also sorry about my english since it is not my first language!` is same! Whats going on?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all the titles by mapping the data `data.data.map((o) => o.title))`, like so:

```js
fetch(
  "https://radiocenter.si/api/module/json/RadioSchedule/JsonModule/GetStreamInfo",
  {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body:
      "RadioStreamId=1&SystemName=&Title=&Description=&Icon%5BId%5D=0&Stream=&XmlStream=&Position=&Activated=true",
    method: "POST",
  }
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.data[2].title));
```

If you just want the 3rd one, then you can access the 3rd element of the array by doing `data.data[2]`, and you can get it's title value by doing `data.data[2].title`. The reason being that `data.data` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and in JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: This gives me all the titles. I just want the 3rd one from top to bottom.

Comment: Try now, `data.data` is an array, so in order to access the 3rd element you need to check at index 2, like `data.data[2].title`